# POST http://domain/backend/api/v1/auth/jwt/create/ 401 (Unauthorized) React authentication and Python backend

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

how to handle axios post request when invalid email or password is provided to login authentication for generation JWT token and also update error msg in redux store.

*From this piece of code I'm trying to post through correct email and password than it works fine but when I'm trying to provide wrong email or password than I'm getting 401 (Unauthorized) and not able to update dispatch(loginFail(isAuth.message))*

```
userApi.js

export const userLogin = (frmData) => {
 

  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.post(APIS.AUTH.LOGIN, frmData);
      console.log(resp);
      resolve(resp);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      reject(error.response);
    }
  })
};


loginSlice.js

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuth: false,
  isError: "",
};
const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginPending: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },

    loginSucess: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isAuth = true;
      state.isError = "";
    },

    loginFail: (state, {payload}) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = payload;
    },
  },
});



signIn.js
const SignIn = () => {

  //handel Submit form
  const handelSubmit = async (evnt) => {
    
    dispatch(loginPending());

    try {
      const isAuth = await userLogin({ email, password });
      console.log(isAuth);

//im getting problem over here I'm not able to update error message when wrong email or password
      if (isAuth.status === 'error' ) {
        return dispatch(loginFail(isAuth.message));   
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error')
      dispatch(loginFail(error.message));
    }
  };
```

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/146WQ.png)

[its work fine in postman but not able to update in error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4IfP.png)

Comment: `resp.data` will have the data you're sending from the backend. To read the error data try `error.response.data`

Comment: thank you Muljayan I solved that but main problem is that I'm getting 401 unauthorised  while passing incorrect Emil or password